# User guide, teacher JavaScript or jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, jquery-plugins

Is there any working JavaScript or jQuery plugin, what can teach step-by-step how to use a website for example? I think about something like what the Facebook applied when introduce something new function.

These scripts show a modal box with half-opacity layer, and an object (for example the user's photo) with a description how can he use it (for ex. click on the image to change it).

Do you know any working example?

I don't have idea how can I find it on Google if exists...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some Links for what you want to achieve:

- http://eragonj.github.io/Trip.js/
- http://usablica.github.io/intro.js/
- http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/11-awesome-jquery-site-tour-plugins-for-guiding-users-with-style/

Answer (score 0):

I think this plugin is similar to what you are looking for:

http://zurb.com/playground/jquery-joyride-feature-tour-plugin